# Itemcollection get latest updated_at item - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, quote, items

We use the following code, to get the last item that was most recent updated.

```
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$itemsCollection->getSelect()->order('updated_at DESC');
$latestItem = $itemsCollection->getLastItem();
```

But for some reason `$latestItem` does not return the last updated item, but the last `created_at` item.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Have you try, $latestItem = $itemsCollection->getFirstItem();

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, we also tried that, but that does not work when you have more than 2 items. For some reason the sorting based on updated_at does not work

Comment: But how 2 items are updated into single cart at the same time?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Not, but when we use `$latestItem = $itemsCollection->getFirstItem();` we get the first added item of the cart. Not the latest "updated" item. The difference between added and updated can be caused by changing qty for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$itemsCollection->setOrder('updated_at','DESC');
$latestItem = $itemsCollection->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: Thanks! This does not work, it loads the first added item to the quote collection, not the latest updated. Removing the setOrder line, is also giving the same result.

Comment: Seems that it works when we use this:

`$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection($useCache = false);`

Comment: If answer help, accept as solution and upvote, so it will help other in community as well.